# selinux: files in /home are created with wrong context

Tags: linux, selinux, home

on Cents 7 folders/files created in /home are getting wrong context

```
# pwd
/home
# ls
# ls -dZ .
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 .
# mkdir -p test/.ssh
# touch test/.ssh/authorized_keys
# ls -ldZ test test/.ssh
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 test
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 test/.ssh
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 test/.ssh/authorized_keys
#
```

The same problem happens when a user's home folder is created with first ssh login (user is then not able to use ssh key authorization due to selinux complains).

The context problem does not exist when a root user does ***su - user***, then home folder is created in right context.

How to learn ***sshd/ssh*** sessions to create new user's home directories in proper context?

No to fix it user need to run ***restorecon*** command, example:

```
# ls -ldZ test/.ssh/authorized_keys test test/.ssh
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 test
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 test/.ssh
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 test/.ssh/authorized_keys
# restorecon -vR test
restorecon reset /home/test context unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0->unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0
restorecon reset /home/test/.ssh context unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0->unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0
restorecon reset /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys context unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0->unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0
# ls -ldZ test/.ssh/authorized_keys test test/.ssh
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 test
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 test/.ssh
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 test/.ssh/authorized_keys
#
```